# How to perform ENTER key operation in iPhone using Selenium

Tags: java, ios, iphone, selenium-webdriver, appium

Please find the below details

```
Appium 1.6.4
MAC 10.12.4
iOS 10.3.1
```

I am able to inspect the webElements for iPhone.
For a text field, I am able to insert a value but I can't perform ENTER key action.

How to achieve this on iOS device..?

Comment: u mean enter key action from the mobile keyborad?

Comment: Yeah..!!! 

How to do this..? Because when I hit Enter function, auto suggested value will get populate.

Comment: Try this. driver.findElement(By.id("Value")).sendKeys("VALUETOPASS",Keys.ENTER);

Comment: No dude..!! Values gets entered but ENTER key action not worked.

Comment: @MohanKumar I am slo facing same issue, even entering any alphabet is not working for me. Can you suggest if you resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Let try with this one

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Value")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

I hope it can be helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `.sendKeys(value+"\n");`

Comment: Hi...

Values entered successfully. But Enter key action not performed.

Comment: My scenario is, when I enter a text, eg : mohan. and I press ENTER, a list of names should display in the form of dropdown. If it is not found. Then word not found message will display.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

1. Enter the string in the input box by using sendkey:

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.id("Value")).sendKeys("VALUETOPASS");
   ```
2. Now launch the device keyboard and do enter:

   ```
   driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys(keys.Enter);
   ```

If the above code doesn't work then try pressing and releasing the keys

```
driver.getKeyboard().pressKey(Keys.Enter);
driver.getKeyboard().pressKey(Keys.Enter);
```

Hope this helps you. thanks.

Comment: "keys.Enter" should be "Keys.Enter".

Answer (score 0):

Use AppiumDriver and try. Most of the above solution should work